# Is it possible to fix my iPad screen? Large areas of black after bending it

Tags: ipad

Some random man sat on my iPad and bend it. Now I have these black parts in my screen. Can you tell me what is wrong with my iPad. Everything works smoothly but these black parts make it difficult to type.

[image: iPad with large areas of black]

Answer (score 3):

Your screen is broken.

The only way to fix it is to have the screen replaced.  If it's still under AppleCare then you'll pay a small amount of money to have Apple replace the screen.

If not under AppleCare, you'll pay more for the screen repair.  Prices will vary among the different repair outlets.  Be sure to do a complete backup of the device before you get it repaired.

Comment: Just curious whether Apple will consider this case under warranty and not deny free service citing attempt at physical tempering?

Comment: Accidental damage is not covered under warranty at all. For this, you need insurance, or cash-in-hand.

Comment: [AppleCare+ covers 2 incidents of accidental damage for a small fee](https://support.apple.com/ipad/repair/service) ($49 in the US).  If you don't have this coverage, you'll be paying out of pocket.